# PHP session empty

Tags: php, session, safari, xampp

I made a simple login function in PHP.
My problem is that there are no session attributes when the browser hits page **login_success.php**

After i store data in the session in **checklogin.php**, i checked if it contained any data by typing : print_r($_SESSION); , this prints 2 object. However, when i try to do the same in **login_success.php** , it comes up empty.

I use xampp and safari.

***Login.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<input name="tb_username" type="text"/>
<input name="tb_password" type="password" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**checklogin.php**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['tb_username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['tb_password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername']= "myusername";
$_SESSION['mypassword']= "mypassword";

//print_r($_SESSION);

header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**login_success.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put session start on the top of your page.

Comment: checklogin.php has no `session_start();`

Comment: Please stop using **mysql_*** functions as they a deprecated.. Start using **mysqli_** or **PDO** instead

Comment: session_start() should come before any output from any page that would be session aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the php documentation: [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

So add `session_start()` to the top of your checklogin.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<?php session_start() ?>` on top of page.

Comment: This seems to become a common mistake; I've already seen 4 different posts yesterday relating to session_start(); you need session_start at the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `php.ini` like this:

```
session.auto_start = 1;
```

Or run following command at your first line:

```
ini_set('session.auto_start', 1);
```

Comment: I do not prefer changes in php.ini. They're easily forgotten if you migrate your project. I didn't know about the ini_set, I'll remember that!

Comment: @Gudgip You're right but there are some settings you have to made in php.ini. You cannot do all in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `session_start()`, there can be a couple of other reasons as well:

1. Disk space is full on your server. This once happened to be the
   case with me. Try checking the available space on your server at
   root '/' (`df -h`).
2. The sessions directory on your server
   (where the session files are being written) has some permission
   issues.