# Slim throwing undefined index from Session variable

Tags: php, slim

I am using the Slim php framework for the first time, so far it has been excellent. I am using a library to handle validation on a user registration form and a session variable to store the input and throw the errors when needed.

I am getting an error telling me my session variable isn't defined. I am struggling to see where I am failing, the session start begins in `app.php` and the following files exist:

Validator.php

```
namespace App\Validation;

use Respect\Validation\Validator as Respect;
use Respect\Validation\Exceptions\NestedValidationException;

class Validator
{
    protected $errors;

    public function validate($request, array $rules)
    {
        foreach ($rules as $field => $rule) {
            try {
                $rule->setName(ucfirst($field))->assert($request->getParam($field));
            } catch (NestedValidationException $e) {
                $this->errors[$field] = $e->getMessages();
            }
        }

        $_SESSION['errors'] = $this->errors;
        return $this;

    }
    public function failed()
    {
        return !empty($this->errors);
    }
}
```

ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php

```
namespace App\Middleware;

class ValidationErrorsMiddleware extends Middleware
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors', $_SESSION['errors']);
        unset($_SESSION['errors']);

        $response = $next($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

The error keeps throwing out pointing at this line:

```
$this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors', $_SESSION['errors']);
```

I can see a session is being logged but without setting an `isset` on this I want to know why it fails?

The actual error itself is: `Notice: Undefined index: errors in...`

**UPDATE**

app.php

```
$app->add(new \App\Middleware\ValidationErrorsMiddleware($container));
```

Middleware.php

```
namespace App\Middleware;

class Middleware
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Validator integrated? Are you sure the validate function is being executed?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: I meant the actual Validator class, not the middleware. Maybe i am blind, but i don't see how the class is integrated into your flow.

Comment: also in app.php

`$container['validator'] = function($container) {
 return new App\Validation\Validator;
};`

Comment: And how is the validate function called?

Comment: they are being passed through as a global - check out the code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150814/discussion-between-danjbh-and-puelo).

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this code 100% working:

```
?php

namespace App\Middleware;

class OldInputMiddleware extends Middleware
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
            /**
            * To prevent Notice: Undefined index: old in app/Middleware/OldInputMiddleware.php on line 16
            */
            if(empty($_SESSION['old'])){
                $_SESSION['old'] = true;
            }

            $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('old', $_SESSION['old']);
            $_SESSION['old'] = $request->getParams();

        $response = $next($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know why rather than suppressing the issue.

Comment: First you need to check  session if empty or not `if(empty($_SESSION['errors'])){})`

Comment: Where would be the best place to check this?

Comment: To get a true result

Answer (score 0):

Add a session middleware and start the session:

```
// Session middleware
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next)
{
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Comment: Is that ok to do?

Comment: Where are you suggesting I do this?

Comment: In your app.php file.

Comment: In PHP you must start the session before you can use the $_SESSION superglobal variable. If you don't start the session handler this variable is always empty. So yes, I think you should give it a try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486215/1461181

Comment: It is being started though right at the top of app.php

Comment: Ok, this is fine. Tipp: Try to find another way to validate the form data. You don't need a middleware for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150841/discussion-between-danjbh-and-daniel-o).